# How to properly use scavenger bots in Dead Space 3

Tags: dead-space-3

As of now, I have two scavenger bots and I'm unsure of how to effectively use them. Does the on-board screen of the scavenger actually indicate where it may find the most resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you play the game, you'll occasionally here a strange noise, its tough to describe but its kind of a 'wub-wub-wub' sound.  This sound indicates a good location for deploying a scavenger.  When you hear it, if you select and 'aim' your scavenger bot, it'll indicate the direction to move in, and when you're near enough to deploy the scavenger bot screen will change to a rapidly flashing circle and it'll beep repetedly.  Click to drop the bot here, and it'll get you some good resources.  If you press the K key you can bring up a status screen which shows the ETA for each bot returning to the bench (I play the PC version, not exactly sure how you access this screen on the console versions).

Rather annoyingly this mechanic isn't really explained at all in the game.

Comment: I actually remember a brief tutorial via the RIG on the scavenger bot now. I guess I forgot the significance of the noises while the bot was searching. Thanks!